# Changing the position of the Bot Role in Discord

Tags: bots, discord.net

I'm currently trying to get my bot working properly. One problem is that the Role that is automatically assigned to the bot is below all other roles and I don't want that the users have to drag them above the other roles. So I decided to try to change the roles position when the bot joins the server but nothing works. Here's my code:
First I connect my method to the event
`_client.JoinedGuild += InviteHandler;`
Secondly, I get the role and try to change the properties.

```
SocketRole BotRole = null;
        foreach(var role in guild.Roles)
        {
            if(role.Name.Equals("KingFive"))
            {
                BotRole = role;
            } else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        BotRole.ModifyAsync(x =>
        {
            x.Color = Color.Gold;
            x.Hoist = false;
            x.Position = 10;
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
```

If anyone could help me, I would be happy :)

Comment: The bot cannot elevate it's own role, that would be a security risk. A user needs to make that change.

Comment: But If I add a big bot like MEE6 he can kick everyone without need to move his role up :c